# Replacement of $compile in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to compile some HTML content in Angular 4, which can be done by $compile in Angular 1.

I tried some suggested alternatives of Angular 2, which are also deprecated.

Some one suggest me the best way to do.

Comment: Which alternatives are deprecated?

Comment: http://www.smartjava.org/content/dynamic-component-loading-angular2-replace-compile
In this post "ComponentResolver" is deprecated.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Comment: If you use angular 5 wait till https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d7a727cc0728a61a707f2c109636c1fa077042c2 is released

Answer (score 0):

The replacement of `$compiler` service in Angular is a [Compiler](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler). You can inject it like this:

```
class MyComponent {
     constructor(compiler: Compiler) {}
```

Read the article [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e#2b99) to understand how it can be used to dynamically compile components.

Here is an example from the article:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const template = '<span>generated on the fly: {{name}}</span>';

  const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
  });
  const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
  });

  this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      const cmpRef = this.vc.createComponent(tmpCmp);
      cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
    })
}
```

Comment: In this approach how can we trigger parent component functions?

Comment: when and why do you need to trigger them?

Comment: I mean I want to add a button and by clicking on it, want to call patent component function.

Comment: @HarshaVardhanPutrevu, did you figure it out? where do you want to add a button? add details to your question using code from my answer

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious what @HarshaVardhanPutrevu is asking. He has, like I do, a (click) directive in an injected element. How do we "compile" the thing so it will actually call the method referenced by the (click). Seems pretty simple. In AngularJS it was a single line of code. I am now seeing solutions that require templates and hundreds of lines of code to accomplish the same thing.